# Android Espresso: UI-Testing with an Ionic Cordova Build

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, android-espresso, ui-testing

Im trying to test the **Android-Build** of an Ionic **Cordova** application with the **Espresso** testing tool from **Android Studio**.

After several dependency issues, the test environment now works. But when I create a test with 'Run -> Record Espresso Test' by selecting elements with the assertion function and run the test afterward, it fails.

The **element cant found** in the views hierarchy. I have no idea why. I already tried so many things, I've also created non-generated test cases identifying elements but vainly.

Does somebody have experience with testing Android-Builds from Ionic Cordova with Android Studios Espresso testing environment?

Hope somebody can help me!

**Test:** (Generated with Espresso)

```
@LargeTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExistReportButton {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void existReportButton() {
        // Added a sleep statement to match the app's execution delay.
        // The recommended way to handle such scenarios is to use Espresso idling resources:
        // https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/idling-resource/index.html
        try {
            Thread.sleep(59700);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ViewInteraction button = onView(
                allOf(withContentDescription("\uF101 Create a Report "),
                        childAtPosition(
                                childAtPosition(
                                        IsInstanceOf.<View>instanceOf(android.view.View.class),
                                        0),
                                0),
                        isDisplayed()));
        button.check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }

    private static Matcher<View> childAtPosition(
            final Matcher<View> parentMatcher, final int position) {

        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("Child at position " + position + " in parent ");
                parentMatcher.describeTo(description);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
                ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
                return parent instanceof ViewGroup && parentMatcher.matches(parent)
                        && view.equals(((ViewGroup) parent).getChildAt(position));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: (with content description: is " Create a Report " and Child at position 0 in parent Child at position 0 in parent an instance of android.view.View and is displayed on the screen to the user)

View Hierarchy:
+>DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=854, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=854, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+-->ViewStub{id=16908679, res-name=action_mode_bar_stub, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+-->FrameLayout{id=16908290, res-name=content, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=818, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=36.0, child-count=1}
|
+--->FrameLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=818, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=3}
|
+---->SystemWebView{id=100, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=818, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=true, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=0}
|
+---->ImageView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=818, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+---->ImageView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=818, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+->View{id=16908335, res-name=statusBarBackground, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=36, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1538)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:92)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:158)
at org.capacitylab.mobile4d.ExistReportButton.existReportButton(ExistReportButton.java:60)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2075)

Tests ran to completion.
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it is a very late answer, but I faced the same problems, when I tried to use espresso with our ionic cordova app. I was able to access the view elements via Espresso-Web using XPath, like this:

```
// find main menu button and click it
String xPathMenuButton = "//*[@name='mainMenuBtn']";

Atom<ElementReference> element = findElement(Locator.XPATH, xPathMenuButton);
onWebView().withElement(element).perform(webClick());
```

So you are directly traversing on what is written in the ionic html files.
But even using this method fails from time to time, e.g. when a notification message (toast) shows up in the app while you run the test.

Hope, this might help someone.